# SSO without redirecting to the Identity provider webpage - workarounds

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml

My situation: our application MyApp must perform Single Sign On to access to third party applications (ThirdApp1 ) contents .
Using SAML ThirdApp1 and ThirdApp2 are Identity providers and during the login process the user is redirected to the login page of ThirdApp1 , inserts login and password and then is redirected to MyApp again, with a token that can be used to access ThirdApp1 contents.

The problem is that our requirements is that the user is shown OUR login page, not the IdP page.

I read on this site that this violates the SAML principle, but could a workaround be to create our login page (that becomes the IdP), and then this page sends login/pass to the real IdP as a POST and returns the real Idp response?

If this is not possible could another architecture like OAuth 2.0 be better for our requirements?
(Please suggest a workaround, not 'this violates the separation between service provider and identity privider')

Comment: "Please suggest a workaround, not 'this violates the separation between service provider and identity provider'". Suggesting a workaround requires such a thing to exist. The closest thing to that in this instance is for a partner to expose their user store for password validation to you across the internet. And that's pretty foolish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by the SAML, OAuth2 or OpenID specifications. If the user credentials must be entered at your site the only option I can think of is some sort of proprietary solution with all the attendant security implications and requiring the participation of the identity providers.